# How do you make a vector of character strings from a vector of objects?

Tags: r

I want to generate a vector of character strings from a vector of objects.

```
Bob <- c(1,2,3,4)
Anne <- c(3,5,7,1)
Tim <- c(4,2,1,1)

People <- c(Bob, Anne, Tim)
```

Now what I want is:

```
> Names
[1] "Bob" "Anne" "Tim"
```

I know you can do this individually with

```
> deparse(substitute(Bob))
[1] "Bob"
```

So I tried to do

```
Names <- lapply(People,function(k){deparse(substitute(k))})
```

but this did not give the expected results. It produced a long list where each element is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "X[[i]]"

[[2]]
[1] "X[[i]]"

...
```

I'm sure this is a fairly easy task, but I can't get it working. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `People <- list(Bob = Bob,Anne = Anne,Tim = Tim)`?

Comment: That really is the easy way to do it, isn't it. Thanks for your help @joran!

Comment: Or since the vectors have the same lengths: `DF <- data.frame(Bod, Anne, Tim)` . Note that a data frame is a list of column vectors having the same lengths.